# sudo python wrong version

Tags: python, macos, version, sudo

I get python 2.7 when running sudo. I've tried changing my .bash_profile and .bashrc from my original user and root, but to no avail.

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:05:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
$ sudo python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I've `alias python='python3'` in both bash configs in both users and sourced them.

How do I get python 3.5 to load with `sudo python`?

EDIT: This is on OSX
EDIT2: I've also tried looking at `which` python.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: try run env | grep PATH and 
sudo env | grep PATH see the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a possible workaround you can add to your bash_aliases (or similar to it):

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
alias sudo='sudo '
```

And then:

```
. .bashrc
```

Answer (score 2):

the two different pythons must be running from different locations on your computer. from the terminal, try running

`whereis python` and `sudo whereis python`. whereis will tell you what path you are running python from.  then, once you figure out where 3.5 is you can run `sudo <path to 3.5>`

Answer (score 0):

Find the location of python for the root user. In the shell type `sudo -i` to change to root user. Then type `which python`.

Changing the python version of the system is not recommended. Some system scripts may face issues for this. You can set alias in the root users `bashrc` or similar files which should be located in `/etc` (e.g `/etc/bashrc` ) directory.

I am not in mac and also I haven't tried this. So the answer is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` doesn't source your (or root's) `.bashrc`, and overrides much of the environment of the calling user, so adding aliases there isn't helpful.

Why not just type `sudo python3`?

Depending on your security settings, `sudo -E python` may work as well.